# C# Twitterizer Streaming GET User

Tags: c#, api, twitter, twitterizer

How can I get tweets live with the Twitterizer.Streaming.dll?

(I only need the content of the tweet, without the user)

I know that I have to do:

```
static void NewTweet(TwitterStatus tweet)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("New tweet: @{0}", tweet.Text));
}
```

But where do I have to call "NewTweet" and how do I start the stream?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from the developer of Twitterizer:
https://gist.github.com/DigitallyBorn/3011921

```
using System;
using Twitterizer;
using Twitterizer.Streaming;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StreamingAPIExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool jsonView = false;

        static OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens()
        {
            ConsumerKey = "REMOVED",
            ConsumerSecret = "REMOVED",
            AccessToken = "REMOVED",
            AccessTokenSecret = "REMOVED"
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.BufferWidth = 100;
            Console.WindowWidth = 100;

            StreamOptions options = new StreamOptions();
            options.Track.Add("#tallycc");
            options.Track.Add("tallycc");
            options.Track.Add("#tallycodecamp");
            options.Track.Add("tallycodecamp");

            TwitterStream stream = new TwitterStream(
                tokens,
                "Tallahassee CodeCamp2001 Example Application",
                options);

            Console.WriteLine("The stream is starting ...");
            stream.StartUserStream(
                StreamInit, 
                StreamStopped, 
                NewTweet, 
                DeletedTweet, 
                NewDirectMessage, 
                DeletedDirectMessage, 
                OtherEvent, 
                RawJson); //optional

            Console.WriteLine("The stream has started. Press any key to stop.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            Console.WriteLine("Stopping the stream ...");
            stream.EndStream(StopReasons.StoppedByRequest, "I'm stopping the stream.");

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void StreamInit(TwitterIdCollection friends)
        {
            if (!jsonView)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} friends reported.", friends.Count));
        }

        static void StreamStopped(StopReasons reason)
        {
            if (!jsonView)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The stream has stopped. Reason: {0}", reason.ToString()));
        }

        static void NewTweet(TwitterStatus tweet)
        {
            if (!jsonView)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("New tweet: @{0}: {1}", tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.Text));
        }

        static void DeletedTweet(TwitterStreamDeletedEvent e)
        {
            if (!jsonView)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Deleted tweet: Id: {0}; UserId: {1}", e.Id, e.UserId));
        }

        static void NewDirectMessage(TwitterDirectMessage message)
        {
            if (!jsonView)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("New message from {0}", message.SenderScreenName));
        }

        static void DeletedDirectMessage(TwitterStreamDeletedEvent e)
        {
            if (!jsonView)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Deleted message: {0}", e.UserId));
        }

        static void OtherEvent(TwitterStreamEvent e)
        {
            if (!jsonView)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Other event. Type: {0}; From: {1}; {2}", e.EventType, e.Source.ScreenName, e.TargetObject));
        }

        static void RawJson(string json)
        {
            if (jsonView)
                Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
    }
}
```